# Modify a trained model input to use another tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

Here is the problem: Let M be a trained model, I want to change its input tensor to a different one which I map original input to a different space.

Here is the code defining the new input tensor:

```
modifier = tf.Variable(np.zeros(shape,dtype=np.float32))
simg = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape)
newimg = (tf.tanh(modifier + simg)/2)
```

If M is trained using keras, I can easily change input tensor to newimg by just doing:

```
M(newimg)
```

However, I have no idea how to do so if M is a original tensorflow trained model.

I searched for quite a while and frustratingly I did not find anything useful, this must be doable -- keras has done it...

Best.

Comment: How are you building the graph? Loading from file? Graph or meta-graph?
 Building from scratch?

Comment: The tf model is loaded from a file (a model trained by others).

Comment: What type of file? Do you have any example code for loading with the original input tensor?